# javascript return value Part 2

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

Had some great help yesterday, and have a followup question/problem.  Regarding an HTML form, when the user clicks onSubmit="return outer()", the function 'outer' only returns one of the two functions inside (either checkname or checkpostal).  How do I get it to check both functions?  Noob question I'm sure, but I want to understand, and not just copy paste from the plethora of forms out there.

```
var postalconfig = /^\D{1}\d{1}\D{1}\-?\d{1}\D{1}\d{1}$/;

function outer() {
    function checkname(f_name) {
        if (document.myform.f_name.value == "") {
            alert("Enter your First Name");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("valid First Name");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return checkname();

    function checkpostal(postal_code) {
        if (postalconfig.test(document.myform.postal_code.value)) {
            alert("VALID postal");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("INVALID postal");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return checkpostal();
} //end of outer
```

The HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="index.php" onSubmit="return outer();" method="post">
  First Name
  <input name="f_name"  type="text" />
  <br />
  Telephone
  <input name="telephone" type="text" />
  <br />
   <input name="Submit" type="submit"  value="Submit Form" >
</form>
```

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check next to the most helpful one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the execution of the function outer() stops whenever your return.

try this single return statement:

```
return  checkname() && checkpostal();
```

Comment: Awesome - that worked perfectly.  Just curious though, what if you had a large number of elements to your form?  Would you just keep adding to the statement?  Ex return checkfirstname() && check lastname() && checkpostal() etc..?

Comment: yes it would. But then, there would be a user experience user problem that was common years ago and tend to be more oftenly addressed: your script would just say something like "some fields are invalid. Guess which ones" when the test fails. With lots of fields it would be a greater idea to validate input of each field separately while typing.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `return checkname();`, your function stops immediately.
There is no way to return a value and then run the rest of the function.

Instead, you need to call both inner functions, then use logical operators to combine them into a single boolean.
For example:

```
return checkname() && checkpostal();
```

Comment: +1. Also (off-topic) a good practice is to use `<label>` for labels in forms. When they are associated to the field with the "for" atribute, you click on them and the assocciated field gets focus. Also, good for screenreaders.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something instead or the returns or at the end do.

return checkName() && checkPostal();

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is technically valid, though may I advise that you define the functions separately.  Use outer simply to call them and check their values, so you'd have:

```
function outer(){   
    return (checkname() && checkpostal());
}

function checkname(){
    // Code for checkname
}

function checkpostal(){
    // Code for checkpostal
}
```